# disallow repetition of given set of characters

Tags: regex

I need to make a regex which will reject string with any given character in set next to each other

```
". / - ( )"
```

For example:

```
123()123 - false
123--123 - false
124((123 - false
123(123)123-12-12 - true
```

This is what i have done so far:

```
(?:([\/().-])(?!.*\1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
(^(?:(?![.\/()-]{2}).)*$)
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tR4vE2)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?![\/().-]{2}).)*$
```

This simply negates the regex `[\/().-]{2}` which matches if two of your characters are next to each other.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/637284) for further explanation.

[Live demo](http://refiddle.co/h3o)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to do it other way around, match strings you don't want to allow.

```
if match [.\/()-]{2}
   not allowed
else
   allowed
end
```